# Binary search for math function

Tags: c++, stl, binary-search, numerical-methods

I have an increasing math function, for example `y = x + 5*x^3 + x^7 + 11*ln x` and I want to find first (positive) `x` such that `y(x) >= 1478`.
Can I use binary search algorithm from stl to solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, you can. Try it.

Comment: Why not using a `for` loop ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, how can I use it? I can write it myself, but the question is about stl algorithms

Comment: @Boiethios, yes, I can use for loop, but in stl library it exists binary search function, can I use it?

Comment: Make a const random access iterator that pretends to give you a sequence element on dereference. Iterator position will give you the answer.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, please write an example how to make such iterator

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Would that work with lower_bound ? STL lower_bound isn't one way binary search.

Comment: @Pavel Why do you want to use STL for this ? Not that I am complaining, but AFAIK  STL does not support one way binary search. i.e binary search on supposedly infinite stream. Today it is '1478', tomorrow you may need to find something else..

Comment: Here your example is a monotonic function. Has it to work also for not-monotonic function, like `y = x + 5*x^3 - x^7 + 11*ln(x)` ?

Comment: @Caduchon, not, just for monotonic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that STL algorithms (`std::lower_bound` is probably your candidate of choice) work on collections. Or more specific: on iterators of collections.
One way to use them for your problem is an adapter: You write an 'iterator' that simply returns the functions value on dereferencing.

The code for this might be pretty big as you need to satisfy all requirements of a [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator). However you can templatize it on your function. Example:

```
template<class F>
FuncIterator{
  typedef int ParamType;
  typedef float ResultType; // Or better: result_of F

  ParamType param_;
  FuncIterator(ParamType param): param_(param){}
  ResultType operator*(){ return F(param_); }
  FuncIterator& operator+=(int diff){ param_ += diff; return *this; }
  //... Other functions required for RandomAccessIterator
}

auto result = std::lower_bound(FuncIterator<MyFunc>(0), FuncIterator<MyFunc>(1000));
std::cout << "First x value is:" result.param_ << std::endl;
```

Again: That iterator is more complex than show here, but you should get further from here. You need some defines, and possible traits. But you need to define it only once and can reuse it for any function. It gets more generic, if you use the std traits to deduce the type of the param and result of `F`.

Final note: Binary search only searches a range! So you must decide on this range when calling `std::lower_bound`. It cannot find 'the first value `x` with `F(x)>=y`' for **any** x but only for any x in a given range.

Comment: Thank you for detail answer. So it isn't any easy way to use binary search from stI, and manual writing of binary search will be really easier than making an adaptor, right?

Comment: Yes. Binary search is meant for ordered containers. Why you want to do is most likely better suited for Newtons algorithm or similar: Finding the root of a function. In your case: `y'(x) = y(x) - 1478` and now find `x` for `y'(x)=0`